# Add One extra item to ListActivity

Tags: android, listview, listactivity

I created a ListView using ListActivity and ArrayAdapter for Sdcard files.
It is working well.

Then i want to add one extra item to ListView.So i added one item to list and called notifyDataSetChanged().
But It shows Force close.Why?
Help me.

```
        FilenameFilter fnf=new FilenameFilter()
        {

            public boolean accept(File dir, String filename) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(new File(dir+"/"+filename).isDirectory())
                    return true;
                else
                return false;
            }

        };
        filelist=sdcard.list(fnf);
        List<String> list=Arrays.asList(filelist);
        Collections.sort(list);
        ArrayAdapter<String> listadap=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.filelist,R.id.listview,list);
        setListAdapter(listadap);
        list.add("Test");
        listadap.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: Logcat:http://pastebin.com/yfXmBwD8

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the content of your ListView dinamically. Create your `CustomAdapter`, extends from `BaseAdapter`. Pass the list to the constructor of the adapter. Rewrite the methods of `BaseAdapter` interface.

And add the add method in the adapter. You'll have the List instantiate in the adapter (save it in a field from the constructor). The method add, will add the item to the 'ArrayList' and then, just `this.notifyDataChanged()` (this, because you're in the `CustomAdapter`)

This method will solve the problem of jumpls in the ListView with Adapter recreation.

Answer (score 0):

Why you placed `List.add("Test");` after setting up the adapter?

Can you change it do this.

```
FilenameFilter fnf=new FilenameFilter()
    {

        public boolean accept(File dir, String filename) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(new File(dir+"/"+filename).isDirectory())
                return true;
            else
            return false;
        }

    };
    filelist=sdcard.list(fnf);
    List<String> list=Arrays.asList(filelist);
    list.add("Test");
    Collections.sort(list);
    ArrayAdapter<String> listadap=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.filelist,R.id.listview,list);
    setListAdapter(listadap);        
    //listadap.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help.

I found another solution to add Button to my Listview.

```
bt_up=new Button(this);
bt_up.setText("Up");
getListView().addView(bt_up);
```

This also works for TextView.